# problems with connecting to database

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting this error each time I run my .php page
It is supposed to show images taken from the server.

This page does show all the images but also error which is:

> "Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
>   given in F:\users\1203158\httpdocs\Adventure_Sports\gallery.php on
>   line 79 "

I do not understand how to eliminate this error

Comment: It means exactly what it's saying. You're passing a string to mysqli_select_db() instead of a mysqli object. Showing us the relevant code will help.

Comment: You're probably porting from `mysql_*()` to mysqli?  Read the docs - and pass your connection resource as the first parameter. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score -1):

You presumably have:

```
$link = mysqli_connect( ... );
```

And my guess is you're doing:

```
mysqli_select_db("database_name");
```

That's how it was done with `mysql_select_db`, but with `mysqli_`, you have to pass the connection handler.

```
mysqli_select_db($link, "database_name");
```

The error is telling you that it's expecting a `mysqli` object (the connection handler) but is getting a string (the database name).

Comment: Would it hurt you to just find the damn dupe instead of making good resources even harder to find on here? You want to help OP you find a suitable dupe.

Comment: -1 Because I agree with the above sentiment.